# 404 на всех страницах в YII1 после перехода

Tags: php, yii, http-status-code-404

доброго

Есть сайт, на YII1 ( старый, древний ). Скопировал его локально, поменял подключение к БД - все круто, сайт заработал. Попытался его перенести на новый хостинг - беда. Сайт не отображается вообще. Если ввести на странице адреса /index.php - 404. Ест-но файл htaccess я не правил, т.к. конфигурация одинаковая. Дебаг включал. локально/хост не выводит ничего

Подскажите алгоритм решения?

p.s. погуглил предварительно ест-но. Проблема не в регистре файлов

```
//htaccess
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8  
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/favicon.ico$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: У вас на хостинге в htaccess так и прописано `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.ru/$1 [R=301,L]` или вместо `mysite.ru` у вас указан нормальный домен?

Comment: в место mysite - указан домен реального сайта. т.к. если напишу реальный - будет нарушение правил форума (за рекламу)

Comment: А у вас на хостинге точно апач есть? Вполне может быть конфигурация в виде связки php-fpm+nginx, тогда .htaccess будет просто игнорироваться, и нужно будет прописать аналогичные  правила уже в конфиге сайта nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще-то Yii1 работает из папки www (Apache нацелен на неё), а там должно быть вот так примерно в файле .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
IndexIgnore */*
php_value short_open_tag 1
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```